# Does “prevalent” have a negative connotation?

Tags: connotations

Here is the definition of *prevalent* from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/prevalent):

> **Prevalent**: existing a lot in a particular group, area, or at a
> particular time:

It doesn't tell anything about the connotation of the word. But in many examples it collocates with negative things. For example:

> These diseases are more prevalent among young children.

In many examples I see that prevalent collocates with a kind of disease. But suppose the following example:

> ... It is a point of view which is still prevalent.

When we use *prevalent* for something like an Idea, does the reader think of a sort of negative idea? I just want to say that this idea is very common, without any judgment!

Comment: What point of view are you talking about? Whether you say "still prevalent" or "still common", it seems as if you are pointing to something that is questionable, that will be disappearing.

Comment: Good and bad things can both be prevalent. I don’t feel any connotation either way.

Comment: Prevalent is used in both good and bad situations. It may be easier to think of negative ideas because we all love to complain! ;)

Comment: The word is neither positive nor negative. In my garden  pink is the prevalent colour.

Comment: @Peter :) Searching for the word 'prevalent' on Google News is very depressing! You'd hardly believe it could be used in a neutral or a positive context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Prevalent" is neither positive nor negative, and it can be used in positive contexts.  Most of the examples of its use place it in a negative context. However the word itself does not imply anything negative. It is possible to say:

> This point of view is still prevalent (and not imply anything negative about the point of view).

As mentioned in comments "good and bad things can be prevalent".